# blank top menu on the Google cloud console

Tags: firefox, google-cloud-console

I'm using the Google cloud console for online training with the last version of Firefox (75.0) and Ubuntu (18.04.4). Just after the login, the home page is briefly displayed correctly, then the top menu disappears, leaving just a blank stripe below the blue header with the search field and the project Id. The page is displayed correctly with Chrome, however.

I think this is related to some obscure Firefox config. Does anyone have an idea about what is going on?

Comment: The menu not showing up is the one with "Dashboard" and "Activity", when you login to the console

Comment: Try again with add-ons disabled. Go to the menu `Help -> Restart with Add-ons Disabled...`

Comment: I already tried that. Unfortunately, this didn't change anything

Comment: Do you have any error messages or warnings in the Firefox Web Console ?

Comment: I have what seems like the same issue. There are a lot of warnings in the console, but no errors.

Comment: I know little to nothing about their project structure, but it seems like they have misstyled the pcc-dropdown-wrapper element. When I set it's display to none, the page seems to look right again.

Comment: Indeed, I observe the same behavior.